# get id of min value, grouped by another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
id, price, date
1, 200, 20180923
2, 100, 20180923
3, 300, 20180923
4, 300, 20180924
5, 200, 20180924
6, 100, 20180924
```

I want to find the minimum price for a given date, and retrieve the ID along with it.

So `SELECT id, MIN(price), date FROM table GROUP BY date` will return the lowest price for each date, but it doesn't tell me which `id` it belongs to.

The expected output here would be

```
2, 100, 20180923
6, 100, 20180924
```

Comment: If multiple ids have the same minimum on a given date, what do you want returned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Think of this as filtering, not aggregation.  I would do:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.price = (select min(t2.price)
                 from t t2
                 where t2.date = t.date
                );
```

This has the advantage that it can make use of an index on `(date, price)`.

If there are duplicate minimum prices on a given date, this will retrieve multiple rows.

One way to handle duplicates is to return them as a list:

```
select t.date, min(t.price), group_concat(t.id) as ids
from t
where t.price = (select min(t2.price)
                 from t t2
                 where t2.date = t.date
                )
group by date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Find minimum price per date Grouping. Use this as a derived table and join with the original table, to get the full row corresponding to minimum price.

Try the following:

```
Select t1.* 
From your_table as t1 
Inner join (select t2.date, min(t2.price) as min_price 
                   From your_table as t2 
                   Group by t2.date) as t3 on t3.date = t1.date and t3.min_price = t1.price
```